# sort posts by getPostViews in functions.php

Tags: posts, views

I have the following function in functions.php that allows sorting alphabetically or by recency. I want to change the alphabetic to sort by most viewed. This is the code I have for the sorter, which is a dropdown select menu:

```
function sorter($wp_query) {

        if(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["sorting"]) == "date"){
            usort($wp_query->posts, 'cmp_date');
        }else if(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["sorting"]) == "title"){
            usort($wp_query->posts, 'cmp_alpha');
        }
}
```

And this is the code for the sorter:

```
function custom_sort(){ 
// retrieve the sorting variables
    $sort_selected = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["sorting"]); ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="sorting">
        <span>Sorting:</span>
        <select name="sorting" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <?php switch($sort_selected){
            case "";
            case "date";
            ?>
                <option value="date">Recency</option>
                <option value="title">Alphabetic</option>
                <option value="views">Views</option>
        <?php break;
        case "title";?>
                <option value="title">Alphabetic</option>
                <option value="date">Recency</option>
                <option value="views">Views</option>
        <?php break;
        case "views";?>
                <option value="views">Views</option>
                <option value="title">Alphabetic</option>
                <option value="date">Recency</option>
        <?php break;
        } // end switch ?>
        </select>
    </div><!-- exit div sorting -->
</form> 
<?php }
```

And I think I need to use something like this (which I saw in another question on this site):

```
<?php $args = array(
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); //http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

//the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

//do your magic
endwhile;
```

But I don't understand how I can translate the code above into code that will fit my current function. I'm using this to get post views:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what you currently have and add a new condition:

```
function sorter($wp_query) {
        if(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["sorting"]) == "date"){
                usort($wp_query->posts, 'cmp_date');
        }elseif(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["sorting"]) == "title"){
                usort($wp_query->posts, 'cmp_alpha');
        }elseif(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["sorting"]) == "views"){
                //create a list of all post ids as an array
                $ids = array();
                foreach ($wp_query->posts as $p) {
                        $ids[] = $p->ID;
                }
                //the query these posts again and sort them by views
                $args = array(
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                      'order' => 'ASC',
                      'post__in' => $ids
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                return $the_query;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: OK I added function cmp_views($a, $b){
 return strcasecmp($a->post_views_count, $b->post_views_count);
} and that is almost working, its not quite in order though.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work since `post_views_count` is not a property of the post object, since it's stored in the postmeta table, and that is why the new query is called. the question is how are you calling the sorter function?

Comment: sorter($wp_query);
$results_count = $wp_query->post_count;

Comment: I got this code from another post, could I somehow use this function to alter the cmp_views? function posts_column_orderby( $vars ) {
if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'post_views' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
    ) );
}
return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'posts_column_orderby' );

Comment: nope like i said post_views_count is not a part of the post object try this: `$wp_query = sorter($wp_query);`

Comment: Instead of sorter($wp_query);? I get this error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object. Thanks so much btw. Also, if I switch my code in functions.php to the original code you gave me, I don't get the error message for the views display, but I get it for the alphabetic and recency. But it still wasn't sorting by most viewed.

Comment: Argh, almost got it I think. However now its limiting my results to the first 20 for views. if ($_REQUEST["sorting"] == "views") {
             $wp_query = sorter($wp_query);
            } else {
    sorter($wp_query);
   }
           $results_count = $wp_query->post_count;
           $per_column = ceil($results_count / 3);

Comment: Thats beacuse only 20 posts have views stored as meta.

Comment: Is there any way I can get them all to show?

Comment: I added this parameter: posts_per_page=-1, but now its not showing the posts with the most views anymore, they are ordered still, but the top 17 most viewed are not there.